# Can I get back my passport after applying for a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen

I need to travel, but the processing time takes up to 15 days according to the website.

Comment: What's the question? Did you ask the relevant consulate?

Comment: 15 days is pessimistic. Some issue within a day or two and some take around 10 working days.

Answer (score 3):

Out of first hand experience in two different EU consulates (Italian and Greek), they actually return the passport to you and on the visa issuance date they will ask for it and they will post it there. Italian embassy even reserved the page with a stamp before handling it to me. I can't confirm this on all consulates or countries but I guess this is how things go with many consulates not only EU ones (such as US, Singapore as well).